# NestJS cookie-parser is not a function error during e2e test

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I have tried to add cookie-parser - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser to my NestJS app:

```
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
consumer
.apply(cookieParser())
.forRoutes('/');
```

When running as normal (compile and run js) NO error is occur and code works as expected, but
when trying to run e2e tests (using Jest, Supertest) on the same code the following error is occur during boot:
`TypeError: cookieParser is not a function`

Also, when using `cookieParser` instead of `cookieParser()`, above-mentioned error isn't occur, but code doesn't work as expected.

During e2e tests, I'm using `Test.createTestingModule` and then `moduleFixture.createNestApplication()`.

Do you have any idea what wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the import to:

```
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! Consider accepting your own answer so that others can see that the problem was resolved.

Comment: That's interesting... I had it working like that (import cookieParser...) previous to nest 7. After upgrading to 7 I had to import it as "import * as cookieParser..." for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

For NestJS **v9.4.x** and above

The following line of code will **STILL** work given the following `tsconfig.json` setup.

**main.ts**

```
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
   ...
   "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   ...
}
```

But if `esModuleInterop` is not set to **true**, then `import x from y` will not work at NestJS **v9.4.x+** and would have to use `import * as x from y` instead.

```
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on NestJS **v.9.4.2**:

```js
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
```